# Write a recursive function which will accept a positive integer from user and multiplies all its digits

Tags: python, recursion

The code that i have written below takes input and then multiplies its digits and give output. If the output is more than 1 digit, then I want to multiply its digits again and keep on repeating this process till the output is a single digit number. I want to do use recursion here.

```
prd = 1
def func_(num, i):
    global prd
    
    if i == len(num):
        return True
    else:
        prd = int(num[i]) * func_(num, i+1)
        return prd
num = input()
i = 0
print(func_(num, i))
```

Now if i run this program and enter input as 24, it gives output 8 which is correct but when i give input like 5555 then it returns 625. Now i want that this program perform same functions again with 625(that is 6*2*5) and keep on doing this till the output is a single digit number.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: "*I dont know what to do next*" What's wrong with the code you have now? What steps have you taken to fix it?

Comment: This smells like a homework. It is ok to ask help to your homework in Stack Overflow, but don't forget to mention about that. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Checking the length is (almost) irrelevant. You're really interested in whether the result is less than 10. If it isn't you can recurse on the the most recently calculated value. Also, your function only needs one parameter (passed as an integer for efficiency). Working with strings for something that's arithmetic in nature is nonsensical

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to declare `prd` as a global. Also, in the case when `i == len(num)`, why do you return `True`? Your function should always return a number.

Comment: @BrutusForcus thankyou. I'll correct my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the function on your number until it is between 0-9, you can do a `loop` until the number is as expected. Pseudocode below

```
number = input
while number > 10:
    number = multiplydigits(number)
    print(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this, if it's necessary to make it recursive.

```
def mult_func(num):
    #
    # multiply the digits here
    #
    if len(str(num)) != 1:
        num = mult_func(num)
    return num
res = mult_func(input("..."))
print(res)
```

Also note that if you are using global variable - which I don't advise - the return makes it kinda pointless.
And it would be useful to provide a clear explanation with examples.

I don't really understand why are you using "i" like that. This makes the multiplication itself recursive and that's why you make only one "step".

Comment: oh okay. I used "i" to increment the value. like intially i = 0. then it increments to 1 for the second digit. but thanks for correcting my mistake.